# Android percentage ProgressBar

Tags: android, view, numbers

in my ProgressBar I want to display the progress percentage in the 0.0 format. I have this code but the result is always rounded up or down, without displaying the number after the decimal point.

```
double value = Double.valueOf(data);
value = numero_a / numero_b *100;
final float numero_float = (float) value;
new Thread(new Runnable() {
    float progressStatus = 0;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    public void run() {
        while (progressStatus < numero_float) {      
            progressStatus += 1;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    tvPercentuale.setText(progressStatus+"%");
                    mProgress.setProgress((int)progressStatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    //this will make sure the format is in XX.X%
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(1);
    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(1);
    .....
    tvPercentuale.setText(nf.format(progressStatus))
```

EDIT:

```
int max = mProgress.getMax();

for(int i=0; i<max; i++){
 int progress = i;
 float progressValue = (float)i/(float)max;
 tvPercentuale.setText(nf.format(progressValue))
 mProgress.setProgress(progress);
}
```

Comment: the problem is that even so the value is rounded.
I want to see 47.8%. but now I see 48.0%

Comment: then progressStatus is being rounded beforehand. Maybe you need to do: float progressStatus = 0F; .... progressStatus += 1F;

Comment: the problem is that `setProgress` does not accept float data but only int.
Is there a way to accept float?

Comment: I think you have your logic a little backwards, here is how I'd do it:

Answer (score 0):

Increase variables by a factor of 10, so:

```
while(progressStatus < numero_float * 10)
```

Then increment progressStatus by 10:

```
progressStatus += 10;
```

then set text as so:

```
tvPercentuale.setText("" + progressStatus / 10.0f + "%");
mProgress.setProgress((int)(progressStatus/10));
```

Comment: the same result. rounded result (example 48.0%), should be accurate, ie 47.8%. perhaps does not support decimals?